# diagnosing random power failures and failures to POST

Tags: windows-7, linux, boot

I have a laptop (Toshiba satellite C650), over the last year it has symptomatically been starting to display some rather peculiar failure behavior, some of the more peculiar behaviors follow:

1. it will randomly shut down
2. it will randomly fail to POST
3. it will randomly fail to do any hdd access while booting (getting stuck at a blinking cursor after POST)

at first I thought this was caused by overheating but bios didn't report that thermal failure had been tripped nor have any sensors read values near critical shutdown, I've had it run at 85C (the failures have happened as low as 30C) but according to all documentation I can find that's pretty far below critical shutdown and even farther from the point where components would take damage.

The second guess was intermittent power supply failure, however this is also seems unlilely as the failure only happens under windows 7 x64 ultimate, under arch linux (running kernel 4.0.6 as of this writing, 4.0.7 by the time I retur after this) it has yet to happen and I am always booted into that partition for weeks on end, the windows one keels over after hours, sometimes days.

The third thing I suspected was a failing memory module, this based on having experiences in the past where windows would BSoD from a failing module but linux would keep chugging (perhaps it maps out bad memory, perhaps my usage pattern just differs so that it never writes to the specific memory, either way) but 48 hours of memtestx86+ per module and another 48 with both modules made me reasonably certain that this wasn't the case.

The fourth guess would be software failure, however I don't know if windows keeps any useful logs for this, nor do I know enough about the platform to diagnose it.

The fifth conclusion is a hdd controller failure but a 12H S.M.A.R.T test reports 0 errors so I can reasonably conclude that is not the case.

The sixth and final conclusion is generic hardware failure, again I'm not entirely sure how I would diagnose that nor why linux would be able to tank it where's windows can't, I'd wager this is one of the less likely options.

As for the computer sometimes never getting to POST... that's another issue I'm uncertain as to how I would debug, the conclusion here is probably some sort of hardware failure.

how to reproduce: reboot computer, whether soft or hard it happens both times, seemingly with a 70ish% proability during soft and only some 50% for hard reset, it seems to be slightly more likely when rebooting from linux (perhaps the hardware dislikes linux?), shuttind down completely and waiting 5-10s before powering on solves this.

as for not loading the boot loader (specifically not reporting any hdd access at all, no audible hdd reads nor any hdd indicator light activity), not sure how to debug this but I'd wager it ties into the other BIOS issue.

the simplest solution is to just replace the machine but I'd be much more interested in figuring out what causes these seemingly related errors as that sounds like a whole lot more fun.

Comment: Any bios updates available for that model?

Comment: no, no new bios updates as it's discontinued; installed the last one some two years ago.

Comment: I would run a memory test, fail to post is either a bios issue or memory issue in most cases.

Comment: I have already run memory tests, they have come out clean (nor have I had any kernel panics or stop screens (colloquially known as blue screens of death), typically one would expect a page fault in nonpaged area stop screen when under windows with failing memory modules).

I further find it unlikely that bios would have decided to fail for no particular reason after an extended period of working; however I'm not dismissing the possibility, I don't have any way to debug it either way.